# Problem displaying property of an object, using EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object, ejs

I'm trying to insert the author's username in reviews in my app, in an ejs template.

the following tag:

`<%= review.author %>`

works as expected, outputting:

`{ _id: 5eff6793e7f26811e848ceb1, username: 'mike', __v: 0 }`

however adding the username property, i.e. this tag:

`<%= review.author.username %>`

this is the code from the appropriate controller:

```
async postShow(req, res, next){

  let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id).populate({
    path: 'reviews',
    options: { sort: { '_id': -1 } },
    populate: {
      path: 'author',
      model: 'User'
    }
  });
  res.render('posts/show', { post });
},
```

Outputs nada. I'm a newbie but I don't know why I'm getting snagged on this seemingly simple issue. Where could I be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a blind guess: you're not passing an Object to your template. You're passing a Mongoose document. Try doing `.toObject()` to your document before passing it to your template

Comment: @blex That sounds possible, but I'm not sure where to use that- I'm using populate to add reviews into my Posts model.

Comment: You could do `res.render('posts/show', { post: post.toObject() });`, but Sven's solution is better. It does the same thing

Comment: Thanks @blex but the issue, persists. Do you know what the best way to debug / get to the bottom of this is?

Comment: I would probably do a `console.log(post);` right before `res.render...` to see if I get the properties I expect to have in that Object, and if I do, just to make sure it's an actual Object, do `console.log("the constructor is ", post.constructor.name);` (should be `Object`). If this is all good, I would check whether the paths I'm using in the template are correct, but they seem to be, since you were able to get `review.author` to print something. Or would it be `post.author.username`?

Comment: okay, so first off the content of .author is an Array (which I have realised by checking my Review model) - does this change things?

Comment: I'll answer myself - I removed the array around the object and it works fine. Feel like an idiot. Thanks @blex

Comment: Don't feel like one, we're all humans. Humans make mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= review.author.username %>`

The above wasn't working because the content of author (a Schema.Types.ObjectId, with ref to the User model) was contained in an object within a superfluous *array*:

```
const ReviewSchema = new Schema({
  body: String,
  rating: Number,
  author: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }]
});
```

Removing the array fixed the issue. I'm not sure why it was included initially. Corrected:

```
const ReviewSchema = new Schema({
  body: String,
  rating: Number,
  author: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to return an object instead of a mongoose document

```
let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id).lean().populate({
    path: 'reviews',
    options: { sort: { '_id': -1 } },
    populate: {
      path: 'author',
      model: 'User'
    }
  });
  res.render('posts/show', { post });
},
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm still seeing the same result.

Comment: what's your post object looks like ? also can you show a snippet of your template

Comment: I was being an idiot, the content of author was an unnecessary array. Thanks for your help